# Camera2 API getOutputSizes not returning largest

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, xiaomi

I'm on a Xiaomi Mi A1, I know for sure that this device can take picture at 4000*3000 resolution, but the method getOutputSizes of Camera API2, return as max size 1440*1080, how is this possible? What am I doing wrong? I've tried YUV_420_888 and JPEG as image format, with the same result.

Comment: Could you find any solution to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find a direct solution to that. I suggest you to have a look at OpenCamera https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ci/master/tree/, maybe they got some workarounds (probably they're simply falling back to normal Camera API).

Comment: The problem is with the hardware of these phones. I have samsung and this phone has been adjusted to work with Camera2 api which is a shame.